# GTK Javascript (GJS) Gnome AppIndicator3 include

Tags: gtk, gjs

I have an app made in GNOME Builder which has a line:

```
 pkg.require({
      'Gio': '2.0',
      'Gtk': '3.0',
      'GLib': '2.66.1',
      'AppIndicator3': '0.1'
 });

const gtk = imports.gi.Gtk;
const glib = imports.gi.GLib;
const gio = imports.gi.Gio;
const appindicator = imports.gi.AppIndicator3;
```

But when I run it it says: `Unsatisfied dependency: AppIndicator3`

But I have an js file that uses:

```
const appindicator = imports.gi.AppIndicator3;
```

And when I run it with `gjs index.js` it works.
I'm new to gnome gtk and can't seem to figure out what is the issue.

Comment: Is it possible that in Builder it is running in a different environment than when you run it manually with `gjs`?

Comment: As I see it it uses same /usr/bin/gjs binary, don't know what would be the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems gnome builder is using flatpack as build environment and you should select Host operating system as a Application runtime